# discord bot that checks if the transfer is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I'm having an issue with my js code. I built a bot that makes a file to play in my server with the name of  who joins, but it's too fast so I want to put something that stops the code until it finishes to make the file

```
        client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async(oldState, newState) => {
      if (!oldState || !newState) return;
      const oldChannel = oldState.channel ? oldState.channel.id : null;
      const newChannel = newState.channel ? newState.channel.id : null;
       const user = await client.users.fetch(newState.id)
       let nome = user.username;
       let messaggio = 'E\' entrato '+nome;
       say.export(messaggio , 'Cellos', 1, 'output.wav', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err)
        }
      })
        online(newChannel, newState, nome);
      });



function online(newChannel, newState, nome) {
  if(newChannel === universoVoice && newState.id !== Botid){
    console.log('entrata');
    const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get(universoVoice);
    if (!voiceChannel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
        console.log("Connesso");
        connection.play('out.mp3');
        client.leaveVoiceChannel;
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
  }else{

    console.log('uscita');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `await online(newChannel, newState, nome);` in order to wait until the `say.export` function is completed